# pgAdmin show object browser text white on white with dark theme

Tags: gnome, themes, pgadmin

When using a dark theme, the object browser uses white background. Is there some way to change this? This question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089110/pgadmin-black-background-font-on-debian) [a few](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200502141620.23716.vegard_p@broadpark.no) times, but no answer still.

[image]

The theme I am using is [E17](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/02/install-e17-gtk-theme-in-ubuntulinux.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also use a dark theme and have the same problem. This is fairly easy to solve though:

1. If the Server connection is open, close it (right click -> *Disconnect server*)
2. Right click on the Server connection and choose *Properties...*
3. In the *Properties* tab click the button in the the second to last item, named *Colour*
4. Select a new colour, say *#3C3B37*
5. Restart pgAdmin

[image]

You have to repeat the procedure for each and every Server connection, but it works.

Comment: OOoooohh!!! I see! Pretty neat for when there are multiple connections within the same instance. Thanks!